# How curve view in android at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, view, android-animation

I have a attached a scrollbar to a recyclerview and now I want to achieve a bending effect while using it.

this is the scroller library - https://github.com/reddit/IndicatorFastScroll

this is the animation i want to achieve -

[image]

I have created this much - https://i.imgur.com/nWD2zWI.mp4

Im stuck with the bending part of it.

### Question

How to bend the view according to users thumb movement?

This is my code -
https://github.com/shrine2000/AnimatedIndicatorFastScroll/blob/master/app/src/main/java/example/indicatorfastscroll/MainActivity.kt#L112

Github repo is provided for a better understanding of the problem.
I have created a github repo of the project - https://github.com/shrine2000/AnimatedIndicatorFastScroll

All helps appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Well, the effect you want to achieve is not exactly bending. It's just drawing letters with different x position. There are no simple ways to bend an existing view in Android. 

I'm afraid you'll have to write your own custom view where you can control the position of the letters. Or fork the scroller library if possible.

Comment: `I have created a github repo of the project` we aren't going to help or contribute to your github repo, you have to include enough information for others to help you _here_. remember, stack overflow serves as a resource to people in the future as well.

Comment: @VictorCold I have check the source code of the library. I agree with what you said those letters are textviews. So according to change in thumb movement animate each individual textview in such a way they form an arc in x axis. I think it's better to fork the library and modify it since there are no methods to access the individual  textviews.